# C++ a class inherit from a type

Tags: c++, inheritance

I created a type, which is a list of priority queues of strings (not my idea, I have to do it):

```
typedef list<priority_queue<string>> L;
L myList;
```

Now I need to create a class M, which will inherit from this type. From what I acknowledged, I need to use templates to do so, but I still have no idea how to do it and I haven't found anything online.

**How do I make a class inherit from a type?**

Comment: Are these `std::list`, `std::priority_queue`, and `std::string`, or are they your own versions? If the former, *why* do you need to inherit from them? Inheriting from standard library types isn’t illegal, but a lot of people seem to consider it a bad idea. And why are you having trouble; it should be no different from any other inheritance.

Comment: @MikeMB You can’t inherit from an object like `myList`; only from a class type.

Comment: @DanielH Yes, they are from std. 
I need to inherit from them, cause it's my home task from school. We usually have to do very weird and useless things in order to learn new constructions and such. I just made it work, but I'm not sure if I did it right. Is it in a good style to put "typedef list<priority_queue<string>> L;" outside of main()? To be exact, before it?

Comment: @Daniel: Sorry miss read the post on my mobile. Of course you have to inherit from `L`

Comment: @Ania I wouldn’t use that typedef, but it might be useful depending on the rest of your code. If you do have it, though, it’s probably a good idea to give it a more descriptive name than `L`, at least something like `QueueContainer` which tells you that it contains queues.

Comment: @DanielH okay, thank you for the tip! But so can I put outside of main()? It sounds like a bad idea to me, but it's the only way it works for me, so I guess it's okay?

Comment: @Ania You can put a `typedef` in a function, or in a class, or in a namespace/global scope, or inside brace-enclosed block. It’ll only be visible in that scope, so it is better not to pollute the global namespace (especially with a less-than-descriptive name like `L`), but you can do it in your own namespace or class without issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```
class foo : L { // Note this is private inheritance
};
```

The type alias is just a name for another type, not a type in its own right. Since `std::list` is a class template and `L` names a complete specialization, you can just do it.

Just be sure not to use it in any polymorphic way that involves `delete`ing a pointer to a `std::list`. It's not designed for it, since it lacks a virtual destructor.

Comment: The problem is, the compiler doesn't see the L type, can I fully legally put it over the class definition, outside of main()?

Comment: @Ania - I don't know what your complete setup is. But as [this minimal example](https://ideone.com/4MBWoP) shows, what I did works as is.

Comment: @StoryTeller but I can't then do `L t=new foo(); t->thing(); delete t;`, because list doesn't have a virtual destructor :(

Comment: Thank you! Might sound like a stupid/easy question, but I found it weird to demand from me to inherit from a type, I've never done it.

Comment: @Ania - It's not stupid at all. It's just something novices better not do until they understand all the implications. And you asking this question is most certainly not a silly thing.

Comment: @Ania You keep saying “Inherit from a type”. All inheritance is inheriting from a type.

Comment: @UKMonkey - No you can't. But you can do `L&& t = foo{}; t.thing();` and the whole thing goes out of scope without UB. Neat, isn't it :P

Comment: @StoryTeller Oh, yeah, I always forget that detail.

Comment: @DanielH - Probably because the only person in the whole world who actually needs to use it for anything is Andrei Alexandrescu :)

Comment: Can I also ask you how does it work? Like how can I use it now that I have a class inheriting from this type? What if I want to make a method that puts some stuff in the queues in the list?

Comment: @Ania - Well, you just add the method to `foo`. As you would for any class. Since `foo` is-a `L` as well, on account of inheritance, you can call any of the `std::list` function on a `foo`.

Comment: Yes but how do I use the methods that are already there? Like push() for example? Since there is no list or queue created I'm quite confused.

Comment: @Ania - There is a list created. Any class contains an instance of all of its bases. Assuming you inherit with `public` then it's as simple as `foo f; f.push_back(/* a std::priority_queue */);`

Comment: I did it like this: "priority_queue<string> a; myClass.push_back(a);" but it shows errors: at the dot it says 'expected an identifier' and then on 'a' it says it's no a type name. I'm so confused by all of this. Do I have to create this priority queue? Or is it created already too and I can just somehow access it? My point here is that I need to read from a file and each line of the file should be put into individual priority queue word by word (from the longest to the shortest). Saying it in case you're confused why I need it.

Comment: @Ania - If we revisit the example I linked to earlier, [what you tried to do should work](https://ideone.com/kQQvnf). Again, it's hard for me to guess what's wrong based off of snippet. Perhaps you attempt to use `a` when it's not longer in scope. I can't really say.

Comment: I found the problem, it was that I used 'foo.' to access something from that class while creating a method of this class. Thank you for all the help and being patient, and I hope I can figure this all out!

Comment: @Ania - Best of luck :)